# What's the proper way to get the entire $_POST?

Tags: cms, php, jinput, jrequest

In Joomla! 2.5.x I could simply run `JRequest::get('post');` but seeing as `JRequest` is deprecated in Joomla! 3.x I should use `JInput`.

At them moment this is the code I'm using to get the entire `$_POST`:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$postData = $app->input->getArray(array_flip(array_keys($_POST)));
```

But this seems rather cumbersome and I run into issues if used in conjunction with `$app->input->set();` I would think there would be a better way?

When searching for this before I've found people saying you can simply run

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$postData = $app->input->post;
```

But when I tried this out I simply got an instance of the `JInput` object.

Comment: [Retrieving request data using JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$postData = $app->input->post;
```

Is the way to go, you will get a JInput object and can use it like JRequest

```
$var = $postData->get('varname', 'defaultvalue', 'filter');
```

The filter could be 'int', 'cmd' or many others - the complete list can be found in this function: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/a3df15f1ddad6d9051d53f939b6afd2f5fca60b7/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L138

If you would only like the array, then you can do

```
$array = $app->input->post->getArray();
```

But you should **avoid** this style of accessing user-data without filtering.

Comment: Often times I need to get the entire `$_POST` without actually knowing the names of the vars I need to get, that is why using the `JInput` object like that is not useful in many cases. Still a good answer though.

Comment: As an FYI The ```$app->input->post->getArray();``` is only valid on Joomla 3.2.0 and later. And in any earlier version (including 2.5) you have to use ```$app->input->getArray($_POST)```

Answer (score 4):

It seems another way to accomplish this is simply pass an empty array:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$postData = $app->input->getArray(array());
```

This will retrieve everything in the `JInput` data var as if you were accessing the `$_REQUEST` super.

This does not work in the Joomla! 2.5.x version of `JInput` though.