# The quickest way to get the POST object in Joomla 3 & 4

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, restful-api

I've been creating a lot of webservices API endpoints in Joomla 4 lately and wanted to ask:
"What's the simplest, fastest, most practical way to get the entire POST object when a controller method gets the incoming request for Joomla 3 & 4. Assume JSON (no HTML forms or XML) and no Joomla filtering".

I've tried to directly decode the POST superglobal i.e.
`$req = json_decode( $_POST )` (generally bad practice to bypass J! entirely).

I've also tried the same with `$_REQUEST` to no avail. (again bad practice).

Here is the code I've come up with after crawling through the core classes:

```
$req = json_decode( $this->input->json->getRaw() );
```

That will take the raw json string and produce an isomorphic PHP object easily accessible via `->` e.g.
`$req->action`, or `$req->data->id`

If you want an associative array (hashmap) as the output, then try this:

```
$req = json_decode( $this->input->json->getRaw(), true);
```

The above code will produce a similar isomorph of the JSON object, as an associative array. e.g.
`$req["action"]`, or `$req["data"]["id"]`

Of course, being a hashmap, the latter option allows you to substitute keys with variables i.e.
`$req["data"]["$key"]`

I'm asking this (and asking for other **working** techniques of accessing the POST object in J! 3 & 4 (leaving 1.5 & 2.5 behind)) as the following references and SO Q/A pages were unhelpful (their solutions didn't yield access to the POST object at all).

Deprecated Joomla docs:
https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

SO Q/A with answers mostly addressing EOL J! versions:
[What's the proper way to get the entire $_POST?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-proper-way-to-get-the-entire-post)

Does anyone know of a **working** technique for J! 3 & 4 that returns the full JSON POST object?